# RadCombobox firing SelectedIndexChanged on every postback on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, telerik, telerik-combobox

so, my problem is, I have a RadCombobox that's filled from the codebehind. But depending on what record is selected, it fires the SelectedIndexChanged on every postback.

After testing EVERY item from my Combobox, I found this:

My combo has these items:

1. Foo
2. Bar
3. Foo Bar

If I select 'Foo Bar', I have this issue, and SelectedIndexChanged is fired everywhere.
This is because the space character that is comming from my database is the character 160(non-breaking space, \u00A0) and not the usual character 32. And according to this blog post(http://www.adamkoch.com/2009/07/25/white-space-and-character-160/), IE handles them diferently.
If after loading my items, I replace the 160 char for the 32, everything works just fine.

My question is: Did anybody have this problem? is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: which version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: IE 8 and 10, both did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. My workaround was check the OldValue and Value in the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
 protected void dd_SelectedIndexChanged(object o, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldValue != e.Value)
        {
            //value changed
        }
    }
```

Comment: My workaround was to change all the 160 chars to 32.
I have this post here, if you'd like to help, maybe it's a bug
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcombobox-firing-selectedindexchanged-on-every-postback-on-ie.aspx